# What package must to import for radioButtons in AS2

Tags: actionscript-2, flashdevelop

I'm doing some multiple choice page but compiler shows error to this line

```
    var myradBut:RadioButton;
```

the message is : The class or interface 'RadioButton' could not be loaded.

I don't know what to import to solve this error.
I'm using Flash Professional 8 of Macromedia, an old software but I'm limited by PC capabilities.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The package for the ActionScript 2 Radio button is `mx.controls.*`, so you need to `import mx.controls.RadioButton`. (`fl.controls.*` is the AS3 package). Documentation for the AS2 version can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002769.html

In the Flash IDE, you will need to make sure you have dragged a component instance from the components panel into your library (or to the stage), as well as importing the class.

If, as your tag suggests, you are editing your ActionScript in FlashDevelop, you will need to set up your project to compile using the Flash IDE: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Projects#AS2_Flash_IDE_Project

Comment: My pleasure. And welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tick this as the answer if it is correct.